# How to retrieve data from a QTableView

Tags: pyqt5, qtableview

I have a QTableView that has two columns. The first one shows names and the other shows their respective email addresses. Am trying to get that information from the QTableView and print it to the command line. i want the information to look like

```
anderson anderson1@gmail.com
wariner warinera@yahoo.com
```

when i run, the code below, it prints None. Here is my sample code

```
identity = []

for row in range(self.table_model3.rowCount()):
    identity.append([])
    for column in range(self.table_model3.columnCount()):
        index = self.table_model3.index(row, column)
        info = identity[row].append(str(self.table_model3.data(index)))
        print(info)
```

Comment: you must provide a [mcve]

Comment: append does not return anything, directly print the list: `print(identity[row])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is printing `None` because you are setting info to the return value of appending data to identity, which is `None`.  To print in the format you want try:

```
for row in range(self.table_model3.rowCount()):
    identity.append([])
    for column in range(self.table_model3.columnCount()):
        index = self.table_model3.index(row, column)
        identity[row].append(str(self.table_model3.data(index))

for item in identity:
    print('%s %s' % (item[0], item[1]))
```

Comment: @eyllanesc ...Yes?

Comment: can you access the elements of the models using indices? Have you tested them?

Comment: Yes, I've tested this answer and used this exact approach many times myself.  Like I said, this assumes his data structure inside the table view model is a nested list called data.  That's obviously what he is doing.  He referred in his code to `self.table_model3.data`, so  I assumed his underlying data store is a nested list named data.

Comment: It is not necessary to assume how is the internal structure, for example if the model is a QStandardItemModel would your code work?

Comment: It wouldn't work with a QStandardItemModel, but like my answer stated, this is assuming that the data structure is a nested list used inside of table model.  Most likely a QAbstractTableModel, which is a common approach.  With the amount of example code that is posted, an assumption had to be made.  If that's not the model style he used, he doesn't have to accept the answer.  But it is still an answer to a problem.

Comment: Answer of this type are of poor quality in my opinion, that's why I ask.

Comment: You're right.  I shouldn't have assumed that.  I believe he is using QStandardItemModel.  I hadn't considered that.  I have changed my answer.